# How to dynamically decorate python unittest class with multiple patches

Tags: python, dynamic, python-unittest, python-decorators

A function is defined in source.py and called in use_source.py. I patch it from test.py like so

**source.py**

```
def example_function():
    print("I don't want this to run")
```

**use_source.py**

```
from source import example_function

def call_example_function():
    example_function()
```

**test.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import use_source

file_names = ["use_source.example_function"]


def fake_function():
    print("I want this to run instead")


@patch(file_names[0], new=fake_function)
class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_example(self):
        use_source.call_example_function()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, I have multiple files like use_source.py that I want to patch, so here is my question

*How do I dynamically call the patch decorator given a list of targets?*

I am looking for something like the this

```
@patch_list(file_names, new=fake_function)
class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
```

I could do this, but I have a high and varying number of files to patch

```
@patch(file_names[0], new=fake_function)
@patch(file_names[1], new=fake_function)
class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
```

Finally, I am looking for a solution that only modifies test.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use a decorator but use patch.start() in the SetupClass method of the test

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import use_source

file_names = ["use_source.example_function"]


def fake_function():
    print("I want this to run instead")

class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        for file_name in file_names():
            patch(file_name, new=fake_function).start()

    def test_example(self):
        use_source.call_example_function()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running python test.py yields the same output as above and allows me to patch a large and varied number of methods!

Answer (score 0):

Decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar for function application. You could write

```
class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

for f in file_names:
    ExampleTest = patch(f, new=fake_function)(ExampleTest)
```

I'm not sure if there is any significant difference between this approach and the solution you found.

Comment: thanks but with the above code I would either get a "local variable 'ExampleTest' referenced before assignment" or not have the patch be applied, ie "I don't want this to run" is printed

Comment: I don't see any reason for the local-variable error. Did you put the loop *in* the class statement, or *after* it? (It should be after, as shown.)

Comment: yes the local variable error was in the class statement, but if I put the loop after the class statement the patch is not applied